# Accessing label value outside of tableview on button click returning null IOS

Tags: ios

I have searched everywhere this question but haven't found any legitimate solution for this. I have a label on `collectionviewcell` each row and a button outside the `collectionview`,what i want is to access all label values on click of button which is outside of `collectionview`. I'm getting value of label on cell which is showing on iPhone screen but getting null value for label which are on scroll or not showing.Here is my code:

```
for (int h=0; h<detailArr.count; h++)
{
    NSNumber * num = [totalProductArr objectAtIndex:h];
    NSIndexPath * indexPath=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[num intValue] inSection:0];
    NSLog(@"indexpath  text is %@", indexPath);
    AppointmentContentCell *cell = (AppointmentContentCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];   
    NSLog(@"text field text is %@", cell.serviceTypeLbl.text);
}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    AppointmentContentCell*cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.serviceTypeLbl.text =[detailArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.serviceCostLbl.text = [costArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.totalServiceLbl.text = [totalServiceCount objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Cells are reused. If a cell isn't onscreen then it can't be accessed. You should be able to get the label values from your underlying data model without needing to access the cell

Comment: Hello Paulw11 can you elaborate this. It will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

As always:

**Get the value from the model (the data source array) rather than from the view (the cell).**

This does the same as your code, but I'm not sure that the logic is intended

```
for (NSInteger h = 0; h < detailArr.count; h++)
{
  NSNumber *num = totalProductArr[h];
  NSLog(@"text field text is %@", detailArr[num.integerValue]);
}
```

To show an example this logs the values of all labels (arrays).

```
for (NSInteger h = 0; h < detailArr.count; h++)
{
  NSLog(@"Service Type is %@", detailArr[h]);
  NSLog(@"Service Cost is %@", costArr[h]);
  NSLog(@"Total Service is %@", totalServiceCount[h]);
}
```

If you would use a custom class rather than a couple of unrelated arrays it could be more convenient